# Is there an opposite of the underscore( _ ) line continuation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, syntax, compilation

The underscore allows me to do things like this

```
    Public Sub derp _
        (x As Integer)
        MsgBox(x)
    End Sub
```

Is there any opposite notation for this? For example, if it was ¯ then I could do

```
Public Sub derp(x as Integer) ¯ Msgbox(x) ¯ End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider to use C# if that's important for you.

Comment: For certain things you can do this..... for example, "If myBool Then doStuff", instead of using multiple lines and EndIf.

Comment: Actually there are very few places that you need to use the underscore these days. In the cases where you do, you probably shouldn't - like in your example

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a colon. But you can't put the function/sub body in the same line as the declaration of the function/sub.

```
Public Sub derp(x As Integer)
    MsgBox(x) : MsgBox("Hello, world") : End Sub
```

You can also try using an action delegate. But it can only have 1 statement if you want to put them in 1 line.

```
Public herp As Action(Of Integer) = Sub(x) MsgBox(x)
```

If you want to have multiple line, you write it like this (you can use colons, if you want):

```
Public herp As Action(Of Integer) = Sub(x)
                                        MsgBox(x)
                                        MsgBox("Hello, world")
                                    End Sub
```

Use Func delegate if you want to return a value instead of Action delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Sure—the colon:

```
Public Sub derp(x as Integer) : MsgBox(x) : End Sub
```

But don't abuse this. The compiler doesn't charge by the line.

About the only time I use it is when I'm establishing an inheritance relationship:

```
Public Class Rectangle : Inherits Shape
   ...
End Class
```

Somehow, that just seems more logical to me than putting the `Inherits` in the class body. And you can't even blame it on my C++ roots, because VB was my first language.

Comment: I'm now mentally trying to construct this question/answer pair as a ternary operation.

Comment: I know about the colon but afaik it only works on the inside bits (like assigning variables or calling functions) but not outside, your example line gives me "First statement of a method body cannot be on the same line as the method declaration."

Comment: That is the only place I use a colon too. Just seems to look right.